# Django-Templates: Is there a middle ground between extend and include?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am developing a webpage with Django and I came across the problem of having certain reocurring elements within a webpage. The base layout inluding the menue for instance wraps the rest of the webpage and can thereby be outsourced by `extend`. Similarly if I have a reocurring element that is completly wrapped by the current webpage without altering html inside it can be implemented by using `include` (for instance a specific Button).

However I have a third category where I do not know how to outsource redundant information:

Lets say I have a card design, that always certain propery and contains of a div, with a header an image and content. I want to reuse this design displaying different contents and i also have different cards on the same page, how do I do that?

Is this really the way to go:

`card_x.html`:

```html
{% extend 'card_template.html' %}
{% block title %} Title x{% endblock title %}
{% content %}
Content x
{% endblock content %}
...
```

`card_template.html`:

```html
<div>
    <h1>{% block title %} {% endblock title %}</h1>
    <div>
        {% content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</div>
```

`mainpage.html`:

```
{% include 'card_1.html' %}
{% include 'card_2.html' %}
{% include 'card_3.html' %}
```

I feel like I want to keep content x inside the mainpage however in this approach I have to put it in seperate files (this also leads to a lot of html-Documents instead of just one per page and one per template). I am in search of something like this made up `include_with` tag I guess:

`mainpage.html`:

```html
{% inlude_with 'card_template.html' %}
    {% block title %} Title 1{% endblock title %}
    {% content %}
        Content 1
    {% endblock content %}
{% endinclude_with %}
{% inlude_with 'card_template.html' %}
    {% block title %} Title 2{% endblock title %}
    {% content %}
        Content 2
    {% endblock content %}
{% endinclude_with %}
{% inlude_with 'card_template.html' %}
    {% block title %} Title 3{% endblock title %}
    {% content %}
        Content 3
    {% endblock content %}
{% endinclude_with %}
```

Is there something like this? And if not how would you engage this problem? Is my approache flawed? I am thankful for any input!

Comment: I am aware of the [`include ... with ...`-option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include). However as far as I undertand it I can only pass variables and not HTML.

Comment: not sure if this is what you are after, but have you looked at writing a custom inclusion tag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I exactly understand, but the following might be what you're looking for:

```
# /includes/card.html
    <div>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <div>
            {{ content }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in your template:

```
{% include 'includes/card.html' with title='Title 1' content='Content goes here' %}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I was aware of this option but my problem with it is that in my case the content could be html itself or at least very long. I feel like the `with`-keyword is mainly for short variables.